# MS-SQL limitations in Azure Free Websites

Tags: mysql, asp.net, azure, azure-sql-database

I have a very simple .Net application having about 10 simple forms backed by a MS-SQL Server database having about 5-6 tables.

I want to host this using Microsoft Azure Free websites model. However, I am not sure what are the restrictions/limitations of using an SQL Server database within a free Azure website model.

As far as I know, the free model provides you with :

> - 10 free web sites per sub region on the AzureWebSites.net domain
> - 165 MB of outbound data per day per sub region, up to 5 GB per region
> - 1 GB of storage per sub region (shared by all web sites)
> - 20 MB of a third-party MySQL database per sub region for the first 12 months

I'd like to know what would be my options in the free model with regards to MS-SQL Server. Would I be able to use MS-SQL Server in the free model. If yes, what would be the restrictions on it?

I checked the Microsoft website for this information, but I don't see the SQL-related restrictions/limitations mentioned explicitly on it.

All I want to know is what are the limitations on using the MS-SQL Server in free model with a Microsoft Azure subscription.

Comment: You'd have to pay for a small Azure SQL Server instance. What kind of data do you have? Could you use Azure Table Storage (not SQL Server)?

Comment: I can be flexible in terms of using technology (Azure table Storage vs SQL Server). I don't have much flexibility in terms of finance. So I'd like to go ahead with what could be best in terms of free model.

Comment: The data I have is very little. Also, its a small website with not more than 20 users. It would be a very low-frequency website which is why I would like to stick within the free model. Would Azure Table Storage be free for me, because I could certainly modify my application to work with it.

Comment: Table Storage is *free* depending on your usage. It's not SQL though it's just a row/column store so there's no way to do aggregations etc, you'd have to manage that in code.

Answer (score 0):

You can leverage the 20MB free SQL Server database that comes along with Mobile Services if you wished: http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/pricing/details/mobile-services/

Comment: Devils in the detail though - *One 20MB Azure SQL Database is available per subscription for the first twelve months of use; standard rates apply thereafter.*

Comment: Fair call.  "Free" will only get you so far and the actual cost of running a 20MB database in Azure isn't that substantial at ~ $5 USD/month.